# CodeIgniter project shows 404 error in nginx server

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, xampp

I have a Codeigniter project which is already created in XAMPP server and its working fine.For some reason, my client wants to shift it to Nginx server. In Nginx server, only default controller is loading.the other pages are showing 404 error. Is there anything I need to setup in Nginx server.I have an another Codeigniter project which is working perfectly in Nginx server.
Is there anything I have to change in my Codeigniter file

I have tried with

```
http://localhost/Project1/website_progressing/ this is working fine
```

`home.php` is my default controller which shows **404 error**

```
http://localhost/Project1/website_progressing/home
```

Comment: did you try with index.php in url? Like "http://localhost/Project1/website_progressing/index.php/home"

Comment: no let me try this

Comment: that also showing 404 error

Comment: did you check this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21972306/codeigniter-nginx-404-error

Comment: thnak you now its working but subfunctions are not working