# Codeigniter functions return "404 Not Found" except index()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller with two functions : `index()` that echoes `Hello World` and `getTs()` that echoes `Hello again`.

When I call `163.XX.XXX.XX/API`, `index()` returns what it's supposed to.
However, when I call `163.XX.XXX.XX/API/index.php/ApiController/getTs`, I get a `404 Not found` error.

I've tried calling the URL in different ways, without `index.php` for example, but it doesnt change anything.

Class names are written with the same case and URI Protocol is set to `REQUEST_URI`.

The server is running Nginx 1.10.3.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Try `163.XX.XXX.XX/API/getTs`

Comment: @NimishaMolia API will be the project name.

Comment: @Alkatell What is your base_url() definition? 
163.XX.XXX.XX/API or 163.XX.XXX.XX

Comment: @Alkatell  check this link for nginx 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44619130/404-errors-with-controller-files-using-codeigniter-3-and-nginx