# CodeIgniter routing not working under Nginx

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx

Ubuntu 16.04 setup by referencing [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/installing-nginx-with-php7-fpm-and-mysql-on-ubuntu-16.04-lts-lemp/) and [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-in-ubuntu-16-04).

I'm able to see my welcome to CI page on `http://x.x.x.x/index.php`, but when I add a test controller and go to `http://x.x.x.x/index.php/test` I get a 404 response. I'm also not using a domain but rather just the IP.

#### /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 2;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/;
}
```

#### /etc/nginx/sites-available/default:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/codeigniter;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name x.x.x.x;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

#### /var/www/html/codeigniter/application/config/config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = ''; //tried putting http://x.x.x.x
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Tried creating a test controller:

```
<?php
class Test extends CI_Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "Hello World!";
    }
}
?>
```

But it doesn't load and I get a 404 response.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try http://x.x.x.x/test not http://x.x.x.x/index.php/test

Comment: no that doesn't work either. 404

Comment: Remove index.php from here $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: no there is still the 404

Comment: which version fo codeigniter are you using

Comment: I'm using 3.1.5

Comment: make sure your test controller name starts from Capital letter like Test_controller and check htaccess file also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154276/discussion-between-bhartsb-and-anil-shrestha).

Comment: file and controller naming issues were explored in chat and appear to be correct.  still getting 404

Answer (score 7):

changing

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
```

to:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

Not really sure why this fixes things, but found it by trial and error referencing:
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/codeigniter/

Here's a bit on try_files:
https://serverfault.com/questions/329592/how-does-try-files-work